# Sublime replace outer part

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible with sublime search/replace to change

```
print "<DIFFERENT CONTENT>"
```

to

```
print("<DIRRENT CONTENT>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Press CTRL+H (replace) and ALT+R (regex search) enter
print\s*(\"[^\"]*\") and replace it with print($1)